# Remover "." "/" e "-" de varchar no select

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, caracteres

Estou realizando uma query para um cliente onde o mesmo solicitou que fosse exibido o CNPJ/CPF das empresas/clientes sem os pontos, barras e traços.
Por exemplo o CNPJ `08.595.551/0001-57` deveria ser exibido `08595551000157`.

Tentei utilizar o comando `REPLACE` da seguinte maneira:
`REPLACE(E.[CNPJ/CPF],'.', '')`

Porém só funciona para um dos caracteres, existe alguma forma de remover todos para que apenas os números sejam exibidos?

Comment: O ideal mesmo seria gravar sem isso no banco de dados, e deixar a interface cuidar apresentar os dados com pontos e etc.

Comment: Concordo com o @Lucas, a melhor forma é deixar limpo no banco de dados e depois usar uma função (sql ou no codigo) para aplicar a máscara

Comment: Realmente seria muito mais fácil, porém ele utiliza um sistema ERP que ao cadastrar os clientes já adiciona com os pontos e tudo mais.

Comment: A partir da versão 2017 do SQL Server está disponível a função TRANSLATE, que permite executar a ação com uma única chamada à função.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você deve utilizar vários replaces:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(E.[CNPJ/CPF],'.', ''),'-', ''),'/', '')
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado Marcelo!